# Python: HoverToool with Datetime-Axis

Tags: python, datetime, bokeh

I am trying to get a proper datetime-visulization for my plot. It just shows the numerical values for the datetime-axis. When I hover over the plot the proper datetime is not displayed.

[You can see it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elzuG.png). 
[image]

Any suggestions for my code? Timestamp is in `2016-01-01 00:45:00`  format.

```
# define source for ColumnDataSource
source = ColumnDataSource(df)
# define figure
plot = figure(plot_height=300, x_axis_type="datetime", sizing_mode="scale_width")
# add a glyph
plot.line('Datetime', 'Preis', source = source, legend='Ausgleichsenergiepreis')
# define hoverTool
hover_tool = HoverTool(tooltips=[('Time', '$Datetime'),('Price', '@Preis')], mode='vline')
hover_tool.formatters = {"Datetime": "datetime"}
plot.add_tools(hover)
# show plot
output_file('Ausgleichenergiepreise.html')
show(plot)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the desired datetime-format to your tooltips (see here:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tools.html

in the section about HoverTool's tooltips). That's just a small addition to your code:

```
hover_tool = HoverTool(tooltips=[
    ('Time', '@Datetime{"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"}'),
    ('Price', '@Preis')], mode='vline')
```